# Can someone help me to make this diamond shape with loop? (Python)

Tags: python

```
n=3
   *
  * *
 *   *
  * *
   *

n=5
    *    
   * *
  *   *
 *     *
*       *
 *     *
  *   *
   * *
    *
```

I tried this but I don't use n=3 or n=5

```
for row in range(5):
    for col in range(5):
        if row+col==2 or col-row==2 or row-col==2 or row+col==6:
            print("*",end="")
        else:
            print(end=" ")
    print()
```

And when I run it

```
  *  
 * *
*   *
 * *
  *
```

I need to make diamond shape with loop, but I'm really new to python, can someone help me?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: This site is really geared towards answering _specific_ questions.  Have you tried working through a tutorial?

Comment: The example uses `n=3` to indicate the length of a side, which works out the same as `for row in range(5)` in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the general form of this function, which takes `n` and produces diamonds that match the two shown in the question, and all other sizes as well:

```
def diamond(n):
    print("n=" + str(n))
    nn = 2 * n - 1
    for row in range(nn):
        for col in range(nn):
            if row+col==n-1 or col-row==n-1 or row-col==n-1 or row+col==3*(n-1):
                print("*",end="")
            else:
                print(end=" ")
        print()

diamond(3)
diamond(5)
diamond(7)
```

Result:

```
n=3
  *  
 * * 
*   *
 * * 
  *  
n=5
    *    
   * *   
  *   *  
 *     * 
*       *
 *     * 
  *   *  
   * *   
    *    
n=7
      *      
     * *     
    *   *    
   *     *   
  *       *  
 *         * 
*           *
 *         * 
  *       *  
   *     *   
    *   *    
     * *     
      *
```